# How do I stop my game ship from accelerating backwards?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I have a game that has a ship object (with JavaFX polygons). When I move the ship with my keys (through EventHandlers and AnimationTimers), it moves up. When I let go, it supposed to change the acceleration to -4 and so then it constantly takes away -4 from the ship's velocity until its suppose to reach 0. However, because the ship can move in all directions, the velocity is sometimes negative when the ship is moving forward. Therefore, when I try to stop the ship when the velocity is negative, it doesn't happen, and the ship keeps moving backwards.

I tried some calculating when the ship's velocity is negative and moving forward but it got a bit too complication and I believe it did not work.

Here is the code for the Ship calculate velocity x method:

```
AnimationTimer calculateVelocityX = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (getAcceleration() == 17)
                setVelocityX(getVelocityX() + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getRotation())) * (getAcceleration() * 0.01)));
            else if (acceleration == -4)
                setVelocityX(getVelocityX() + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getTempRotation())) * (getAcceleration() * 0.01)));
        }
    };
```

```
    AnimationTimer shipAccelerationTimer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            getShipImage().setLayoutX(getShipImage().getLayoutX() + getVelocityX());
            getShipImage().setLayoutY(getShipImage().getLayoutY() - getVelocityY());
            wrapShip();
            if (getVelocityX() == 0 && getVelocityY() == 0) {
                getCalculateVelocityX().stop();
                getCalculateVelocityY().stop();
                setAcceleration(17);
                setCounterOne(0);
                setCounterTwo(0);
                setCounterThree(0);
                getShipAccelerationTimer().stop();
            }
        }
    };
```

This code will move the ship backwards since the velocities can never actually reach 0 because of the decimal precision. However, if I say when velocity is less than 0, this is not possible from what I said above.

Image of the velocity signs when the shipped is moved in a specified direction:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sxNi.png

Therefore, I cannot just have "when velocity is less than 0", since like in quadrants 2, 3, 4, I can be moving forward but have either negative x, y velocities or both.

Comment: May consider using `<= 0`? And/or rounding the values to `Int`

Comment: @kleopatra I don't like giving my code away. Sorry. Hopefully the code I provided is enough.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The <= 0 cannot work since sometimes the velocity is negative but moving forward. I will try rounding the values to Int though and then stopping when it hits 0. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I don't like giving all my code away, you're right. If I don't provide much code, I am okay with just an answer on how to solve it. If I did, it would be best if there is a code solution.

Comment: Please see the new edit of an image representing the signs of the velocities.

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you? Then why do assume that anybody wants to see _your_ holy production code? It's all about writing a reproducible (implying being both compileable and runnable) example for the sole purpose of demonstrating the error in your code/logic. Either do or see your question be closed as not answerable (probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerating backwards won't work, since the direction is not constant.

Consider the case where the ship accelerated upwards and then turned to face the right by exactly 90° after accelerating but before coming to a halt. The part velocity component in y direction will never become 0, but the movement direction in x direction will continue changing...

You need to slow down in the direction opposite to the current movement, if there is no acceleration instead of doing this depending on the direction your ship is currently facing.

I btw recommend not using 3 annotations for the speed change here. This just makes your code unnecessarily complex. You can do the whole thing in a single animation.

**Example:**

(Code kept simple rather than well-designed)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    double w = 600;
    double h = 600;

    Rotate rotation = new Rotate(0, 0, 0);
    Line ship = new Line(0, 0, 20, 0);
    ship.getTransforms().add(rotation);

    ship.setLayoutX(w / 2);
    ship.setLayoutY(h / 2);

    Pane root = new Pane(ship);
    root.setPrefSize(w, h);

    class Animator extends AnimationTimer {
        // the current speed
        double vx;
        double vy;

        // the direction the ship is facing
        double directionX = 1;
        double directionY = 0;

        // the current acceleration magnitude
        double acceleration = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (acceleration > 0) {
                // speed up in the direction the ship is currently facing
                vx += directionX * acceleration * 0.001;
                vy += directionY * acceleration * 0.001;

                acceleration -= 0.1;
            } else if (vx != 0 || vy != 0) {
                // decelerate
                double speed = Math.hypot(vx, vy);

                // constant deceleration opposite to velocity
                double correctionFactor = Math.max((speed - 0.01) / speed, 0);
                vx *= correctionFactor;
                vy *= correctionFactor;
            }

            // update position
            ship.setLayoutX(ship.getLayoutX() + vx);
            ship.setLayoutY(ship.getLayoutY() + vy);
        }

    }

    Animator animator = new Animator();
    animator.start();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // make sure the ship always faces the mouse
    root.setOnMouseMoved(evt -> {
        double dx = evt.getX() - ship.getLayoutX();
        double dy = evt.getY() - ship.getLayoutY();

        if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) {
            // handle special case of mouse being in the same position as the ship
            dx = 1;
        }

        // assign normalized direction
        double magnitude = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
        animator.directionX = dx / magnitude;
        animator.directionY = dy / magnitude;

        // update ship rotation
        rotation.setAngle(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(dy, dx)));
    });

    root.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        // accelerate
        animator.acceleration = 17;
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. First, I am still not sure of your second paragraph. If you could explain it in more detail no why the y velocity will never go to 0, thanks. Also, I do not get why directionX is 1 and directionY is 0 for determining the ship's direction. Also, I am not sure how Math.atan2 works. Besides my questions, this exactly solves my problem.

Comment: Any acceleration won't change the component of the velocity orthogonal to the acceleration. That's a bit hard to explain, if you've never worked with vectors to represent movement, position and acceleration. The initial values of the direction do not matter much. However it matches the direction of the line in this case. This direction is overwritten as soon as the mouse moves on the scene anyways. As for `atan2`: usually you use the inverse tangens (atan) to calculate the angle based on y/x but this way you loose information (y/x == -y/(-x)). atan2 takes care of this...

Comment: (y and x are the positions of the mouse relative to the position of the ship in this case. It's simply a way of calculating the ratation angle necessary to make the line face the mouse.)

Comment: Okay, but why did you specifically set it to directionX = 1 and directonY = 0 when instantiating them?

Comment: Also, one more thing if you could answer, I do not get how this works: double correctionFactor = Math.max((speed - 0.01) / speed, 0). Why is it called a correctionFactor and how does the code work for deaccelerating the ship? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I chose the origin of the line to be it's own `(0,0)` coordinates, so "the direction it's facing" is towards `(20,0)` i.e. the direction is `(1,0) = (directionX, directionY)`. For calculating the new speed I'm simply recucing the magnitude of the velocity: `v' = v * (|v| - 0.01) / |v|`; this results in `|v'| = |v| - 0.01` preserving the direction (`v'` is the new velocity,`v` the old one,`|x|` is the magnitude of the vector `x`) i.e. every step reduces the magnitude by `0.01` using `Math.max` prevents the speed from getting negative as well as dealing with rounding errors in the calculation...

Comment: Okay, I get the direction part: +- 1 and 0 represent the compass coordinates direction magnitudes i.e. NE is (1, -1) depending on how you look at it and it's initially facing to the right. It's a float value to consider all values of rotation. Thanks. I also get how the formula first gets the unit vector direction by x/|x| then applies the direction onto a decreased value of the velocity. If there were no x/|x|, subtracting a negative can result in it going negative forever if the velocity was negative. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I appreciate your code and I see you did JavaFX a lot. Do you recommend any books or any other tips on how to get better using JavaFX or coding games in general? I am eager to apply real-world formula physic formula on games but notice that it gets unnecessarily complex and there is another simple way of implementing the same thing with simple math and code. I also thought the use of the Max function for decreasing velocity was really neat.

Answer (score 0):

If I was in you I would think about considering velocity with his magnitude and direction where Magnitude>=0 and direction is ±1 compared to positive X and positive Y.

Comment: How would this help? I have to stop the ship in any direction, where the velocity X and velocity Y can be negative.

Comment: Please see the new edit of an image representing the signs of the velocities.

Comment: @user12055579 It would help 'casue at that point
 if (V.Magnitude<0) V.Magnitude=0

Comment: I am still confused on how to implement this in code since I don't understand what you mean by that.